# React Native cannot read property of 'state' undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a router file that defines the stackNavigation and TabBarNavigation as follows:

**Router.JS**

```
const Homestack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Region: {screen: Detail}
});


const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeStack},
    Region: {screen: Settings}
});

export default Tabs
```

And I am creating appContainer in my index file as follows:

**Index.JS**

```
import Tabs from './src/Config/router'


const AppIndex = createAppContainer(Tabs)
const App = () => {
  const {viewStyle} = styles;
    return <AppIndex />;
};
```

But when I compile i am getting

> Cannot read property of 'state' undefined

But it works fine for if I don't use stackNavigation as follows:

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Region: {screen: Settings}
});

export default Tabs
```

Please let help me understand what might be causing the issue.

Edit:
[image]

I tried the following way of adding StackNavigation to TabNavigation but it still fails:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen')} title="Home"/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Settings!</Text>

        </View>
      );
    }
  }

const Homestack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Region: {screen: DetailScreen}
});


const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Homestack},
    Region: {screen: SettingsScreen}
});


export default Tabs
```

Comment: Can you provide your stack trace as well? It's probably coming from Details component, so if you could provide some code from it that that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi I have added the screenshot. I have changed and added 'Detail' component in createBottomTabNavigator and it works fine(withoutStackNavigation).